# Tensorflow while_loop for training #2

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38994037/6618884) I asked how to solve overhead problem by using **while_loop** for training (which allow to evaluate **train_op** several time by call only one **run**). After that I create 4 thread and run one **while_loop** per thread for optimization in parallel. Is there native mechanism in TensorFlow for such parallel optimization?

I use Ftrl optimizer.

Thanks!

**EDITED:**

In my situation I have big data set, which I read gradually in main thread and enqueue to FIFOQueue. I use batch optimization and one optimization step on small batch (ideal only one element) takes little time (I use linear model), since that I want to do all optimization step in one **run** call, without returning to python interpreter on each step (because overhead problem). Now I call run as many times as number of threads.

Comment: That's what queue runners do -- they create several Python threads and do `while(True): sess.run` in parallel

Comment: But QueueRunner is for enqueue data, isn't it ? Is there example, where queue runners using for training model? Nevertheless, it dose exactly what I do, am I right? I add more details to my question