# Tensorflow while_loop + tf.train.batch

Tags: tensorflow

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38994037/tensorflow-while-loop-for-training) is described a simple process which I use for training. I want to change input pipeline. Now I create .tfrecords file, and do `TFRecordReader -> tf.train.batch -> tf.parse_example`. If in the body of the loop I do only the last stage, the example will be dequeued only once (when the loop is created). If I add `tf.train.batch` in the body, it creates a dequeue operation inside the loop, but an enqueue as well (but I'm not sure...)

So, the question is - How can I use `tf.train.batch` to enqueue example in while_loop (and parse)?

I parse examples after dequeue because I have sparse data.